# Unwished indent and dash added in first line of yaml file with ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am currently using the following code to load in a single-document template YAML file, changing it slightly, and generating (i.e., dumping) different new deployment files. The code looks like this:

```
import yaml
import copy
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import (DoubleQuotedScalarString as dq, 
                                      SingleQuotedScalarString as sq)
#As requested, below a summary of the functionality of the function define_exp_parameters
def define_exp_parameters(experiment_template, deployments):
    deployment_list = []
    for duration in range(30, 71, 1):
        for cpu_cores in range(1, 4):
                        
            exp_doc[0]['spec']['annotationCheck'] = 'true'
            deployment_list.append(copy.deepcopy(exp_doc)) 
    return deployment_list   
        
testyaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    
with open(template_dir, 'r') as read_file:

    deployments = testyaml.load_all(read_file)
    deployments = list(deployments)
    # define_exp_parameters is used to generate different YAML deployments, each of which are added to a list, which is returned. The list basically consists of x YAML deployment definitions which are later dumped in seperate files.
    deployments = define_exp_parameters(experiment_template, deployments)
            
i = 1
for deployment in deployments:
    with open(save_dir) as created_file:
            
        testyaml.default_flow_style = False
            
        testyaml.dump(deployment, created_file)
            
    i += 1
```

The template looks like this:

```
apiVersion: litmuschaos.io/v1alpha1
kind: ChaosEngine
metadata:
  name: teastore-chaos
  namespace: default
spec:
  annotationCheck: 'false'
  engineState: active
  appinfo:
    appns: default
    applabel: app=teastore
    appkind: deployment
  chaosServiceAccount: litmus-admin
  components:
    runner:
      runnerAnnotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: 'false'
  jobCleanUpPolicy: delete
  experiments:
  - name: pod-cpu-hog
```

This results in files with the following structure:

```
- apiVersion: litmuschaos.io/v1alpha1
  kind: ChaosEngine
  metadata:
    name: teastore-chaos
    namespace: default
  spec:
    annotationCheck: 'false'
    engineState: active
    appinfo:
      appns: default
      applabel: app=teastore
      appkind: deployment
    chaosServiceAccount: litmus-admin
    components:
      runner:
        runnerAnnotations:
          sidecar.istio.io/inject: 'false'
    jobCleanUpPolicy: delete
    experiments:
    - name: pod-cpu-hog
```

However, my desired structure would be the following (i.e., same as template):

```
apiVersion: litmuschaos.io/v1alpha1
kind: ChaosEngine
metadata:
  name: teastore-chaos
  namespace: default
spec:
  annotationCheck: 'false'
  engineState: active
  appinfo:
    appns: default
    applabel: app=teastore
    appkind: deployment
  chaosServiceAccount: litmus-admin
  components:
    runner:
      runnerAnnotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: 'false'
  jobCleanUpPolicy: delete
  experiments:
  - name: pod-cpu-hog
```

Basically, there shouldn't be a dash in the first line (which, for some reason, is automatically generated/added as it isn't in the original template file) and there shouldn't be an extra first indent in the whole structure (which I think comes along with the dash). I am using ruamel.yaml for dumping as it preserves the explicit single quotations in strings (using the imported package). I have tried looking for similar cases and the [ruamel.yaml](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) documentation but I wasn't able to find the reason/solution for this.

Comment: The indent comes indeed along with the dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having the source of `define_exp_parameters()` it is impossible to exactly describe what goes wrong. But before calling that `deployments` is a `list` containing a single element that is a  `dict` (with keys `apiVersion`, `kind`, etc.). And after that call `deployments` is a list of single elements list (which elements is aformentioned dict). You iterate over the "outer" list and dump a single element list, which, in block style, gives you the `-` which is the block sequence element indicator.

If you can't fix `define_exp_parameters()` to return a list for which each element is a dict again, you can just dump the first element of `deployment`:

```
testyaml.dump(deployment[0], created_file)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! As requested, I added the functionality of define_exp_parameters() in the code section. Basically, it just edits some of the values. I tried your solution and it worked. Thank you a lot!

Comment: That you have `exp_doc[0]` in that function  shows that `exp_doc` is a list which you then append to the value to return. You could do something like `deployment_list.append(copy.deepcopy(exp_doc[0]))`  there instead of the solution I gave in my answer.

Comment: True, but would it matter computing-wise? Thanks for taking your time! I appreciate it.

Comment: IMO the only thing that matters is understanding where the extra list layer in the data comes from that causes the `-` and the indent.  Whether that extra layer should not be added in the first place, or where in the program to remove it, depends on your usage of the data, potential reuse of the routines in other situations etc. That's up to you, computationally there is  only a minuscule overhead having the extra layer.